# How can I toggle the title attribute of a element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-check" title="click to accept"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check checked" title="undo"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check" title="click to accept"></i>
```

As you see everywhere there is `checked` *class name*, then the title of that element has to be `undo` *(Also the title of other elements have to be `click to accept`)*. I mean `checked` class name and `undo` title have to be **unique**.

Now I'm toggling the *class name* like this:

```
$('.fa-check').on('click', function(){
   $el = $(this);
   $el.not($el).removeClass('checked');
   $el.toggleClass('checked');
});
```

In other word, I'm removing `checked` class from all elements and then toggling `checked` class for clicked element. Now I want to know, how can I do the same thing for `title` attribute ?

Comment: `$el.not($el).removeClass('checked')` Doesn't make sense.

Comment: why aren't you using a checkbox? how do you expect someone who isn't able to use a mouse to be able to click?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm following what SO does .. it doesn't use a checkbox for those checked icon *(for marking an answer as the accepted one)*.

Comment: @stack, [please don't appeal to authority](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority) to excuse inaccessible design decisions. The developers behind SO are humans and are therefor not perfect. This is one of those cases where it's in your best interest to not follow their lead.

Comment: @stack, I would be remiss if I didn't note that SO includes separate keyboard controls to navigate the site (hit `?`).

Comment: @zzzzBov What do you mean "separated keyboard"? btw I pressed `?`, but nothing happens.

Comment: @stack, "separate keyboard controls" is what I wrote. I'd forgotten that you have to check the [setting in your preferences](/users/preferences/).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the attribute of the title when the element is checked or unchecked using `$(this).attr('title')`.

**jQuery**

```
$('.fa-check').on('click', function() {
   $el = $(this);
   $el.not($el).removeClass('checked');
   $el.toggleClass('checked');

   var title = 'click to accept' ;
   if ($el.hasClass('checked')) {
      title = 'undo';
   }
   $el.attr('title', title);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c78vvo43/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

#### `prop` is preferred over `attr`

For example:

```
$('.fa-check').on('click', function(){
   var $el = $(this);
   var title = $(this).prop('title');

   if(title === 'undo'){
     // Reset state
     $el.removeClass('checked').prop('title', 'click to accept');
   } else {
     // Mark as checked
     $el.addClass('checked').prop('title', 'undo');
   }
});
```

Comment: what happens when `$(this)` is already an accepted answer? *(not a new answer which will be marked as the accepted one)* ..! That's why I've used `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`.

Comment: In your original code it looks like you attempt to remove all `checked` classes and add it back it the clicked one. That's what this does. Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Yes .. I'm trying to do something else .. I'm trying to remove all `checked` classes **except `$(this)` element**. Because I need to know whether current element is an *undo* or *marking as accepted one*. So if I remove all `ckecked` classess, there isn't any clue to know that anymore.

Comment: Ah, okay. I updated my example to do what I think you want.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.fa-check').on('click', function(){
   $('.fa-check').removeClass('checked');
   $('.fa-check').attr('title','click to accept');
   $(this).toggleClass('checked');
   $(this).attr('title','undo');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f42a85og/)

Comment: This doesn't toggle the current title. It always sets `undo` for `$(this)` element.

Comment: along with that it will always toggle the class to 'checked' when u click on it since previously it will not have 'checked'

Answer (score 1):

*Isn't this simple:*

```
$('.fa-check').on('click', function(){
    $('.fa-check').removeClass('checked').attr('title', 'click to accept');
    $(this).addClass('checked').attr('title', 'undo');
});
```

Comment: what happens when `$(this)` is already an accepted answer? *(not a new answer which will be marked as the accepted one)* ..! That's why I've used `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`.

Answer (score 1):

*HTML:*

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

*CSS:*

```
.checked {color: red;}
.fa-check {cursor:pointer;}
```

*JQUERY:*

```
$('.fa-check').click(function() {
if($(this).attr('class')=='fa fa-check checked'){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
}else{
    $('.fa.fa-check.checked').removeClass('checked');
  $(this).toggleClass('checked');
}
});
$('.fa-check').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr('title','click to accept');
    $('.fa.fa-check.checked').attr('title','undo');       
});
```

*YOUR HTML SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS*

```
<i class="fa fa-check" title="click to accept"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check" title="click to accept"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check" title="click to accept"></i>
```

*YOUR JQUERY SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS*

```
$('.fa-check').on('click', function(){
   $el = $(this);
   $elnot = $('.fa-check.checked');
   $elnot.not($el).removeClass('checked');
   $elnot.attr('title', 'click to accept');
   $el.toggleClass('checked');
   if($el.hasClass('checked')){
      title = 'undo';
   }
   $el.attr('title', title);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c78vvo43/3/)

[YOUR EDITED JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c78vvo43/6/)

automatically change check on mouse click. maybe this is what you looking for.